# Is it safe to load a scene with LoadSceneMode.Additive while unloading the same scene index in an UnloadAsync call in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning the workflow of using sub scenes in Unity, but some little details elude me. For reference, my loaded scenes are:

- Bootstrapper and Game State (Index 0)
- Game Scene (Index 1)
- Audio Handler (Index 3)

In a case where I need to refresh my game scene, my instinct would be to do the following:

```
void RefreshScene() 
{
    int sceneNumber = 1;
    SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(sceneNumber, UnloadSceneOptions.UnloadAllEmbeddedSceneObjects)
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNumber, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
}
```

But I fear I might be opening myself to weird race conditions? Does Unity handle this case gracefully? Or would I need to actually wait for the scene unloading to be done first in this case with code such as

```
IEnumerator RefreshScene() 
{
    int sceneNumber = 1;
    var task = SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(sceneNumber, UnloadSceneOptions.UnloadAllEmbeddedSceneObjects)
    while(!task.isDone)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNumber, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    OnLoadIsDone();
    yield return null;
}
```

The problem however with the above code is that I get a frame where no camera is present.

Comment: Instead of going by the index - which I think could indeed lead to issues - you should rather store the `Scene` reference and use the overload of `UnloadSceneAsync(Scene)` so you can be sure the correct `Scene` instance will be unloaded .. is there a special reason why not using `LoadSceneAsync` as well?

Comment: In your case because of `Because loading is set to complete in the next rendered frame, calling SceneManager.LoadScene forces all previous AsyncOperations to complete, even if AsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation is set to false. To avoid this, use LoadSceneAsync instead.` it would make sense to also load async ;)

Comment: @derHugo: The main reason why I was not going async is because I found no reason to do so. At the moment that code was ran, the screen was obscured by the transition scene, so I didn't really mind a blocking operation.
That is until, of course, I figured out I could actually start loading the scene at the moment the transition started to make everything appear smoother. So I'm very grateful for your comment : D

Comment: @TEEBQNE Thank you for this answer. If you want to post it as an answer I would mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is safe. You can also use additive load on a loading scene, unload the precious scene completely and when that's done load it again. Have the loading scene have a UI Overlay Canvas that is above all other UI. Once the scene is fully loaded unload the loading scene.

I can write a more detailed answer when not on mobile if you need.